# Validar extensión en formulario de subida múltiple de archivos

Tags: php, array, archivo, servidor

Estoy intentando validar las extensiones de los archivos que se suben al servidor, pero cuando pruebo un subida de un archivo, con un extensión que daría completamente en un error, resulta que se llega a subir al servidor.

Código PHP (código para la subida al servidor)

```
foreach ($_FILES['file'] ['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
    if($_FILES['file'] ['name'] [$key]){

        $filename = $_FILES['file'] ['name'] [$key];
        $temporal = $_FILES['file'] ['tmp_name'] [$key];


        //VALIDAR EXTENSIONES
        $extensionesValidas = array("jpg","jpeg", "png", "gif", "mp4", "mov", "avi", "zip", "rar");
        $errores = 0;
        $arrayArchivo = pathinfo ($nombreArchivo);
        $extension = $arrayArchivo ['extension'];


        //DEFINIR CARPETA DESTINO.
        $directorio = "uploads/";

        if(!file_exists($directorio)){
            mkdir($directorio, 0777);
        }

        $dir = opendir($directorio);
        $ruta = $directorio.'/'.$filename;

        //MOVER ARCHIVO A LA CARPETA DESTINO.

        if(move_uploaded_file($temporal, $ruta)){

            header('Location: ../subirarchivos');

        } else {
            header('Location: extensionnovalida/');
        }

        closedir($dir);
```

Añado este código:

```
   if(!in_array($extension, $extensionesValidas)){
        //header('Location: extensionnovalida/');
        $errores = 1;
    }
```

Pero no funciona. ¿Qué podría estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Primero, ¿dónde pones ese código? Luego, ¿dónde analizas si hay errores o no? Finalmente, ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer cuando haya error?

Comment: Cómo usarías ese `$errores`? Con qué archivo probaste?

Comment: Respondiendo el Comentario de @Triby, Primero, el código lo pondría dentro de "foreach". Segundo, no analizaría el error, solo cambio el contenido para más orden. Tercero, cuando se ejecute el error, quiero que se redirija a una pagina que tengo completada (en el código está comentado la redirección).

Comment: Respondiendo el comentario de @Alfabravo, El error lo usaria por si hay algun cambio que no quiero que haga, por ejemplo, por defecto $errores = 0, si hay algun error se cambiaria a $errores =1, y terminaria la ejecución y redirije a la pagina que le defino. He probado con varios archivos, todas las extensiones que están en el codigo, extensiones de textos, ejecutables, etc...

Comment: En una de esas pruebas, validaste el contenido de `$extension` al correr pathinfo? Confírmalo. PD. Por pura salud mental, sé consistente al usar comillas dobles, tienes `'jpeg'` en el array (pero eso no cambia nada de tu pregunta).

Comment: Si, si la validé.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando el formulario de subida múltiple similar al de [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.multiple.php):

```html
<form action="el_archivo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Enviar estos ficheros:<br />
  <input name="file[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="file[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar ficheros" />
</form>
```

La parte para subir los archivos será será:

```php
$dir_destino = 'uploads/';
$extensionesValidas = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "mp4", "mov", "avi", "zip", "rar");

foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key=>$temporal) {
    if(!$temporal) { continue; } // Si no se usaron todos los inputs
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
    $file_ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // Extension
    if(in_array(strtolower($file_ext), $extensionesValidas)) {
        $ruta = $dir_destino . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
        if(move_uploaded_file($temporal, $ruta)) {
            echo 'Archivo subido correctamente';
        } else {
            echo 'Error subiendo archivo, verifique los permisos de escritura';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Error, Tipo de archivo no válido';
    }
}
```

[*] Nótese que hay una línea que tiene un `continue;` En caso de que el usuario no haya usando alguno de los inputs, esta línea omite esa entrada.